# Show User Control View inside Tab Item when Tab Item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, tabcontrol

I have created a couple of UserControl views and now I want to show the corresponding view when a tab item is clicked. So one tab item gets one view. I would like to do this in MVVM but don't know how.

Please take a look at the following code and give me some advice on how to achieve that:

**The MainView (with the TabControl only):**

```
...
<TabControl Name="pnlFormButtons" 
                Margin="25"                     
                Background="Black"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelTab}"
                >
        <TabItem Name="tabInventurartikel" Header="Inventurartikel hinzufügen"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond" Foreground="Black"
                 FontFamily="Verdana"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 >
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabSonderartikel" Header="Sonderartikel hinzufügen"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond" Foreground="Black"
                 FontFamily="Verdana"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="2">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabAnlegen" Header="Lieferschein anlegen"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond" Foreground="Black"
                 FontFamily="Verdana"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 IsEnabled="False">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabDrucken" Header="Lieferschein drucken"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond" Foreground="Black"
                 FontFamily="Verdana"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 IsEnabled="False">
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="tabHilfeseite" Header="Hilfeseite aufrufen"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond" Foreground="Black"
                 FontFamily="Verdana"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 IsEnabled="False">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabFehlerMelden" Header="Fehler bzw. Bug melden"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond" Foreground="Black"
                 FontFamily="Verdana"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 IsEnabled="False">
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
...
```

**The MainViewModel (only relevant code):**

```
...
    //Binding Property SelTab - It binds to the selected tab item
        private string _selTab;
                public string SelTab
                {
                    get { return _selTab; }
                    set 
                    {
                        _selTab = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("SelTab"); //INotifyPropertyChanged
                        GetSelTab(); //check which tab item is selected and display the corresponding view
                    }
                }
            public void GetSelTab()
                {
                    UserControl usc = null; //initialize user control object
                    switch(SelTab) //which tab item is selected?
                    {
                        case "tabInventurartikel": // = TabControl.SelectedItem
                            usc = new Inventurartikel(); //Initialize (Show) Inventurartikel.xaml
                            SelTab.Content = usc; //Here I don't know how to actually show the view in the tab item because SelectedItem.Content does not exist...
                            break;
                        case "tabSonderartikel":
                            usc = new neuerArtikel(); //same problem here...
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
...
```

NOTE:

> The views for the tab items are basically just user control forms that I want to show inside the tab item when the corresponding tab item is selected. 
>   I shouldn't post them here because I want to keep the focus on the actual problem as simple and as clear as possible. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to bind the tab control's item source to a list of view models. Then, if you add/remove view models, tabs are added/removed accordingly.

Main window xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding TabName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TabControl x:Name="tbCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Loaded="tbCtrl_Loaded" SelectionChanged="tbCtrl_SelectionChanged" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <uc:DeviceTab/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The important thing is the binding of `ItemSource`.

Tab control view model:

```
class TabControlViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
}
```

Tab control code behind Loaded event. Here you can add view models and the tab control sets up the tabs accordingly:

```
private void tbCtrl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tabControlViewModel = new TabControlViewModel();
    tabControlViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel());
    DataContext = tabControlViewModel;
    tbCtrl.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

This only works if all tabs are the same. There's also a solution if you need different user controls for each tab. In that case, you need to specify a data template for the tab item's content. Basically you can tell it to load user controls based on the type of the view model. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that, but I've seen examples for it. I know it's not the exact answer you need, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying but the tabs are not the same. It does not have to be an MVVM solution but it would be preferred because that is the part I am lacking experience with and I was hoping that some experienced C# head could guide me to the right way to solve this issue.

Comment: I figured that one should NEVER create a view inside a view model because it is an MVVM violation. I decided to resharp my project by using the MVVM framework Caliburn Micro. This way I can use interfaces like INotifyPropertyChanged and IService without having to worry about the implementation. For me as a beginner of MVVM a very nice way of making my life easier. This thread can be archived or closed if needed.